# hydra parse error

Tags: hydra

```
$ hydra 127.0.0.1 -l admin -P /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt http-get-form “/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: security=low; PHPSESSID=4jpaqj7i6d88g7im1hlpq21ad9”

zsh: parse error near `&'
```

Comment: That's not a `hydra` parse error, it's a `zsh` parse error. The error message even tells you so!

Answer (score 2):

Delete the quotes and write them again.

It seems like you copied that command from somewhere and the quotes came formatted.